# Can someone help me recall what this framework / technology is called?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, service, singleton

When I started to learn about WPF and MVVM recently, I came across some sort of framework or technology in .NET that made it really easy to request a service of some kind.  In my particular case, I've got an assembly that handles writing application preferences to an XML file, and I want to let all of my assemblies in the larger application use this to write their own set of preferences to the same file.

I thought it was Unity, but when I looked it up, it didn't seem to be what I read about.  The only clue I have for you is that I think it's called a service (it's NOT WCF), and you can request the service two ways: one way gives you the same service each time, like a singleton, and the other way gives you a new instance each time.

Please help to jog my poor memory.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're referring to Microsoft's [Common Service Locator](http://www.codeplex.com/CommonServiceLocator).

Although you might just be talking about [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) in general, of which [Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity) is one such library.  There are many other DI libraries including [AutoFac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/), [Ninject](http://ninject.org/), [StructureMap](http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/index.html), and [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html).  The CSL is just a way of abstracting the DI library itself, which is useful when you're a framework/library designer and want to use DI without depending on a specific implementation.

Comment: Thanks, Castle Windsor was it!!!  I guess I could be well-served by any of the other libraries that you had mentioned.  I am very new to this sort of thing, so maybe I should just give CSL a try?  DI is really no different than if I passed in an interface to my preferences library to the assemblies that need it, right?  It's just a heck of a lot cleaner, right?

Comment: @Dave: CSL isn't actually a DI library, it's just a wrapper for any of those other libraries.  Unless you yourself are designing libraries intended for reuse, there's no reason to bother with the CSL (Microsoft actually says that explicitly although I can't find the page at the moment).  And, DI isn't a way of *passing* interfaces, it's a way of abstracting their *instantiation*.  But you should read the DI article, there's not enough room in a comment box to describe it in detail. ;)

Comment: Yes, I understand that they aren't for passing interfaces, I was just asking for confirmation that they are an elegant alternative to passing interfaces.  Coming from C++ land, the latter is all I know how to do.  DI sounds like a good replacement.  I'll read the articles, now, thanks! :)